# Puppet Enterprise 3.3 Not Adding Modules to Classes

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-dashboard

I am running Amazon Linux with a stock install of Puppet Enterprise 3.3.  When I launch the command:

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-ntp
```

As per the puppet labs documentation, it does not show up in my available classes list.  I installed Puppet Enterprise as sudo, but puppet commands are only available from ec2-user .  Everything else appears to be working.

Command run as root:

```
[root@puppet bin]# ./puppet module install puppetlabs-ntp
Notice: Preparing to install into /home/ec2-user/.puppet/modules ...
Notice: Downloading from https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com ...
Notice: Found at least one version of puppetlabs-ntp compatible with PE (3.3.0);
Notice: Skipping versions which don't express PE compatibility. To install
the most recent version of the module regardless of compatibility
with PE, use the '--ignore-requirements' flag.
Notice: Found at least one version of puppetlabs-stdlib compatible with PE (3.3.0);
Notice: Skipping versions which don't express PE compatibility. To install
the most recent version of the module regardless of compatibility
with PE, use the '--ignore-requirements' flag.
Notice: Installing -- do not interrupt ...
/home/ec2-user/.puppet/modules
└─┬ puppetlabs-ntp (v3.1.2)
  └── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.3.2)
```

Comment: Did you run it with `sudo`?

Comment: Tried it both ways.  I attached the result above.

Comment: I see what the problem is now, but I don't have the answer handy. Someone will come along with it shortly, I'm sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  Thank You Michael for addressing it.  The key was I changed the basepath to point at the ec2-user directory in puppet.conf.  Once I changed it back, it started working.  Thanks!